# Sum of ideals-Intersection of algebraic sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

In my lecture notes I have the following:

$$
\begin{array}{ccl}
\text{Sum of ideals} & & \text{Intersection of algebraic sets} \\[4pt]
I+J & \longrightarrow & V(I+J)=V(I)\cap V(J) \\
\operatorname{Rad}(I(V)+I(W)) & \longleftarrow & V\cap W 
\end{array}
$$

I understand the first one, that the sum of two ideals is the intersection of the algebraic sets of these two ideals.

But I don't understand the second one. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: I civilized your formatting somewhat.  If you look at my edit, you will see how it's done. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Ok, thank you! @MichaelHardy I didn't know that... Do you have any idea for my question?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm quite rusty in this kind of algebra . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* $V \cap W$ is the *largest* algebraic set contained in both $V$ and $W.$ Hence $I(V \cap W)$ is the *smallest* radical ideal containing both $I(V)$ and $I(W).$ Thus $I(V \cap W)= \text{Rad}(I(V)+I(W)).$ (The correspondence between *largest* algebraic set and *smallest* radical ideal follows from [*HILBERT NULLSTELLENSATZ*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz))